# Customise x-axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very large data frame (2 columns) in terms of records. I have plotted the graph in ggplot2. The X axis is the time and the Y axis is values. Over a specific interval from time 50 to 60, I want to make the ticks increments to be smaller such as (50,51,51,53,...59,60). For the rest of the axis, it is fine to have the ticks incremented by 10. So,I would expect to have X-axis values like :

```
10,20,30,40,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,58,60,70,80,90,..190,200.
```

I know, I can modify the ticks through `scale_x_continuous` by using `breaks` and `minor_breaks`. However, I'm not getting the expected output. Here is my try:(note: have created data just for example as my data is very large).

```
data:
-----
x<-seq(1:200)
y<-seq(51,250,by=1)
df<-data.frame(x=x,y=y)

code:(Update based on @Didzis Elferts suggestion) 
-----
ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y))+geom_line(size=1.6)+ 
   scale_x_continuous( breaks=c(10,20,30,40,seq(50,60,by=2),seq(70,200,10))
                       ,minor_breaks=seq(50,60,by=2) )+
   +theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=16),axis.text.y=element_text(size=16))+
   +theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=16),axis.title.y=element_text(size=16))+ 
   +theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = 1))+xlab("Time")+ylab("value")
   +theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(0.8,"cm"))
```

Based on the suggestion below, the only problem now is the values of X-axis during the interval between 50-60 is not clearly appeared.
[image: sample of O/P]
Any suggestions to make it clear!!

Answer (score 23):

With argument `minor_breaks=` you set the minor gridlines. To set numbers under the x axis all number should be provided with argument `breaks=`.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y))+geom_line(size=1.6)+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(10,20,30,40,seq(50,60,by=1),seq(70,200,10)),
          minor_breaks=seq(50,60,by=1))
```

For the second problem - you set `axis.ticks.x=element_line(size=5)` inside `theme()` - that makes your axis ticks wider so they appear as small rectangles. If you want to make axis ticks longer use `axis.ticks.length=`.

```
+theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(0.5,"cm"))
```

Comment: You are right. However, after I applied you suggestion, the values of the minor breaks overlapped. I can't see the values. Can we increase the space between each minor tick, so the values can be read. Maybe if we change the font or the angle ?

Comment: You can't directly increase space between miner breaks. Also the font size and angle can be changed for all x axis labels together.

Comment: @SimpleNEasy, those values overlap because your minor breaks are too close together: `minor_breaks=seq(50,60,by=2)`.