# R: Specify special points in line graph using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I want to specify two points on the line graph as below using ggplot. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 0, xend = 2, yend = 25), linetype=2) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 25, xend = 2, yend = 25), linetype=2) + 
  geom_point(data=data.frame(lat = c(25), long = c(2)),aes(long,lat),colour="blue",size=4) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 0, xend = 1, yend = 20), linetype=2) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 20, xend = 1, yend = 20), linetype=2) + 
  geom_point(data=data.frame(lat = c(20), long = c(1)),aes(long,lat),colour="blue",size=4)
```

You do with geom_segment and/or geom_point.

[image]

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764140/ggplot2-customised-x-axis-ticks) for how to change the axis labels/ ticks.

EDIT: I edited my post for the sake of the second point.

Comment: A suggestion: if there are multiple segments needed, you could consider creating a dataframe with all the relevant information, prevents repetition of `geom_segment`. In this case, you could do something like `segment_data <- data.frame(x=c(2,0,1,0),y=c(0,25,0,20),xend=c(2,2,1,1), yend=c(25,25,20,20))` and then `b + geom_segment(data=segment_data, aes(x=x,xend=xend,y=y,yend=yend))`.